# how to define two different layout managers in a single recylerview? i have used two recyclerviews for layout managers

Tags: android-recyclerview, nestedscrollview

how to define two different layout managers in a single recyclerview? actually now i defined the layouts using two recylerviews.Even i want to scroll both the recylerview at the time.

this is my code.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".LinearLayout" >



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/grid_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:layout_height="250dp"/>



    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linear_recycler"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_height="250dp"/>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you solved this yet?